# Tcl debugging in Tkcon using idebug

Tags: tcl

I have a function which I need to stop using a breakpoint and check the value of a variable. For example in the code below, after doing a register write through erf_wr, I want to check whether the value was written correctly to different variables like mac_tx_rst, port_rst etc.

```
   proc set_mac {maskrange speed duplex} {
    global gz contra env ptp_info


     erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg mac_tx_rst 0
     erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg mac_rx_rst 0
     erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg port_rst 0
    erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg phy_rst 0
  }
```

Is the only way to do this is to introduce "puts" for every variable? I am using tkcon and I am trying to use idebug. In the tkcon console I tried this:

```
  (test.hw) 596 % idebug break erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg mac_rx_rst 0
  (test.hw) 597 % idebug on
  (test.hw) 598 % set_mac 0 100 fdx
```

But the code did not stop at the breakpoint and completed.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `idebug break` (just that) in your command at the point where you want to stop and examine. Something like this:

```
proc set_mac {maskrange speed duplex} {
    global gz contra env ptp_info

    erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg mac_tx_rst 0
    idebug break
    erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg mac_rx_rst 0
    erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg port_rst 0
    erf_wr -s dev_$port clock_cfg phy_rst 0
}
```

Use the command `h` to get a list of things to do.